# I want a save db when back button selected only

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview

My IOS application program have tableview in navigation controller secondview.

I want to save the fact that I came in tableview .

so I set save code on two mathod

```
                  - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
                  -(void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification
```

in tableviewcontroller

Here is problem , because I don't want to save when I select a table cell and turn another

view. but it save.
because view is diappearing when display turn another view (=selected cell content)

I want to save when (only) back button selected in tableviewcontroller.

Is it available? how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the save code in the `viewWillAppear` method of your first view controller. You can pass the data to save to the first controller and when the view appear save the data.